# How to parse and split a double in c++

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, double, precision

I have these three numbers:

```
double n1 = 1.1
double n2 = 1.10
double n3 = 1.101
```

and I expect to convert them into strings to separate the decimal parts to use them somewhere else. Therefore I want to have the following:

```
string s1 = 1
string s2 = 10
string s3 = 101
```

I read that this is not possible using `std::to_string` as it always returns all the decimals, e.g. `s3` would be something like `101000`.

I then tried the following:

```
double n3 = 1.101;
std::ostringstream strs;
strs << n3;
std::string str = strs.str();

boost::char_separator<char> sep(".");
boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tokens(str,sep);

for (const auto& t : tokens) {
    EV << "separated parts " << t << endl;
}
```

This works fine in `n1` and `n3` cases but when I use `n2` it returns `1` instead of `10`.

I am thinking how to solve this and the only thing is to count the precision before converting to string and then setting the precision again.

Is this a viable strategy?
How can I count how many digits are there after the point?

Comment: `1.1 == 1.10`, there are no differences.

Comment: Simple elementary math, it doesn't matter how many zeros you have at the ending of the decimal part. So, 1.1 == 1.10, also 1.10 == 1.100000000000000000...

Comment: Why not use [`std::modf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf)?

Comment: I know but this is a code for me. `1.1` means something different than `1.10`.
If the input is `1.1` I want to be able to distinguish from `1.10`

Comment: @brid Why do you need the values as double initially?

Comment: @bird Then read them as strings and compare them as such.

Comment: @MrPromethee I know it makes no sense but in other parts of the code the double is required. I could change this but it would take long. I was just wondering if there was a method to read the double and save it as string without losing/adding digits

Comment: If 1.1 and 1.10 means different thing in your senerio, maybe you should save the double values in string or some customized data structure. Or if these values are saved in double, it's not possible to restore the decimal part. By the way, can you tell me your application senerio and why do you save these data in double?

Comment: @brid You could store the values a string and convert to double when necessary

Comment: @MrPromethee yes that is what I am trying to do but as I wrote in the question it is not working. Do you have a better idea than mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your numbers initially arise in datatype `double`, then I see no chance to separate the fractional part as written in the literal used for initialisation. This information is simply lost as I'll try to explain in the following paragraphs:

Note that literals `1.10` and `1.1` both stand for a numeric literal of type `double`. The compiler will translate both literals into a floating point representation / binary representation, and `1.10` and `1.1` will achieve exactly the same binary representation. Hence, you won't have any chance to find out whether a double value had been initialised with a literal `1.1` or `1.10`.

Things get even worse when we consider that decimal number `1.1` does not have an exact binary representation but leads to a repeating fraction:

```
0.1₁₀ = 0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011…₂
```

So when you print out literal `1.1` (or `1.10`, which is the same), it depends on the precision on which you want to round:

```
std::cout << "1.1 is..." << std::setprecision(6) << 1.1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "1.1 is..." << std::setprecision(17) << 1.1  << std::endl;
// 1.1 is...1.1
// 1.1 is...1.1000000000000001
```

This means that - once stored as a double value, you get different results depending on the precision you use for printing the value; this also applies for converting the fractional part into a string, which is actually the same as printing with a particular precision.

Even more worse, due to being not able to represent every decimal value exactly in a binary form, two different decimal values can yield the same value in binary form:

```
double n1 = 1.1;
double n2 = 1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625;

if (n1 == n2)
    std::cout << "equal!" << std::endl;
// Output: equal!
```

So you cannot distinguish `n1` and `n2` any more.

A lot of words, and a short conclusion:

If you want to distinguish `1.1` from `1.10`, or if you generally want to find out the fractional part of numeric literals as written in your source code, then you have to store them **initially** as strings, not as doubles.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're not familiar with what a 'floating point' number actually is.

A double is a floating point number as described on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point . Basically `1.10` is the same as `1.1`, which is the same as `1.1000000` and so on.

Now, there are solutions for this called 'fixed point numbers', more commonly known as 'decimals' and 'numerics'. If you are familiar with database engines, you know that 1.10 is a numeric(3,2) and 1.1 is a numeric(2,1). Notice how the type changes and defines both the precision (number of digits) and the scale (number of digits after the comma). However, C++ doesn't natively support decimals.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't understand how this helps me. Are you saying that what I am trying to do is not possible?

Comment: @brid, a `double` doesn't store the information about how many digits there are. So no, using a simple double it's not possible. You can of course wrap it in a custom data structure and add that information while parsing, or use a fixed point library.

Answer (score -2):

It's just simple math.
The parser just convert your x.10 into x.1 :)